# Accessing and showing modal located in another component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a `PersonList` component, wherever user clicks on `List.Item` I want to pass some details like `personId` to `PersonModal` and display it. I'm using Ant Design component for modal.

Below is what I tried, but unfortunately I'm getting an error like:

> Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted.
>   This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application.
>   Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};`
>   class property with the desired state in the PersonModal component.

`PersonModal.js`

```
import React from "react";
import {Modal} from "antd";

class PersonModal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(this.props.personId)
    }

    state = { visible: false };

    showModal = () => {
        this.setState({
            visible: true,
        });
    };

    // handleOk (...)
    // handleCancel (...)

    render() {
        return <Modal
            title="Basic Modal"
            visible={this.state.visible}
            onOk={this.handleOk}
            onCancel={this.handleCancel}
        >
            Modal body
        </Modal>
    }
}
export default PersonModal;
```

`PersonList.js`

```
import React from "react";
import {Icon, Input, List, Avatar} from "antd";
import PersonModal from "PersonModal/PersonModal"

class PersonList extends React.Component {

    showModal(personId) {
        const modal = new PersonModal({personId: 123})
        modal.showModal()
    }

    render() {
        const persons = this.props.list;
        return (
            <div>
            <List
                itemLayout="horizontal"
                dataSource={persons}
                renderItem={item => (
                    <>
                    <List.Item onClick={this.showModal(123)} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}>
                        <List.Item.Meta
                            avatar={<Avatar src="avatar.png"/>}
                            title={<span>{item.firstName} {item.lastName}</span>}
                            description={<span>{item.city}, {item.country}</span>}
                        />
                    </List.Item>
                    </>
                )}
            />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

What would be correct way of approaching this problem? Since I am new to React i suppose this is not a correct approach.

Reproduced issue on [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pwqga4?file=index.js)

Comment: if you share a working stackblitz which replicates this issue, it'l be much easier to help

Comment: @AkberIqbal Based on answer below and current issue I prepared [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pwqga4?file=index.js)

Comment: please check forked version without error at https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7phgq2?file=PersonList.js

Comment: Thank you @AkberIqbal looks like same moment I realised that it has to be an arrow function inside `onClick`.

Comment: Now you'll always remember this when you come across this error :) - would appreciate if you accept the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to track the **visible state** of the **PersonModal** in the **PersonList** component. You should have a boolean variable to control the visibility of the PersonModal.

and the **PersonModal** will not control its visiblity state, rather it will get it from its clients , in your case the client is **PersonList**. so lets begin with the code

first, edit the **PersonModal** component to expect props from its clients

```
class PersonModal extends React.Component {
    // handleOk (...)
    // handleCancel (...)

    handleCancel = () => {

        // because the client controls the visivlity state of the component
        this.props.hideModal();
    }

    render() {
         /// this.props.isVisible is required, and it will be a boolean true or false.
        const shouldBeVisible = this.props.isVisible;

        return <Modal
            title="Basic Modal"
            visible={shouldBeVisible}
            onOk={this.handleOk}
            onCancel={this.handleCancel}
        >
            Modal body
        </Modal>
    }
}
export default PersonModal;
```

so now your **PersonModal** component expexts a prop; which is **isVisible** prop.

```
class PersonList extends React.Component {

    state = {
        // the client controls the visibility of the modal with this state key;
        showModal: false,
        personId: null
    }


    // edited
    showModal = (personId) => {
       // set state to update the UI and show the PersonModal
        this.setState({
            showModal: true,
            personId: personId
        });
    }

     hideModal= () => this.setState({showModal: false});

    render() {
        const persons = this.props.list;
        return (
            <div>
             // now PersonModal will only be visible when the parent of it tells it to
            <PersonModal 
            isVisible = {this.state.showModal} 
                hideModal= {this.hideModal}
/>   
            <List
                itemLayout="horizontal"
                dataSource={persons}
                renderItem={item => (
                    <>
                    <List.Item onClick={() => this.showModal(123)} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}>
                        <List.Item.Meta
                            avatar={<Avatar src="avatar.png"/>}
                            title={<span>{item.firstName} {item.lastName}</span>}
                            description={<span>{item.city}, {item.country}</span>}
                        />
                    </List.Item>
                    </>
                )}
            />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

hope it helps you;

this is how the problem is approached in the React world

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I tried to use the code from your examples but unfortunately got some errors: `Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.` and `Unhandled Rejection (Error): Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.` Any clue about that?

Comment: sorry my bad, i edited the showModal function , check that out

Comment: I actually copy-pasted all your code, but unfortunately I'm getting still same error

Comment: what about your handleOk function, how did you write it

Comment: make that an arrow function too, like this, handleOk = () => { /// };

Comment: Previously I had it like that (copy-paste from ant design docs): `handleOk = e => {
        console.log(e);
        this.setState({
            visible: false,
        });
    };

    handleCancel = e => {
        console.log(e);
        this.setState({
            visible: false,
        });
    };`

Comment: hows ur handleOk now? since i didint implement it, make it an arrow function , like this, handleOk = () => { console.log("ok);}

Comment: Can you take a look here on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pwqga4?file=index.js)? It's same error like I'm getting locally

Comment: Ok, problem solved, apparently value of `onClick` has to be an arrow function.

Answer (score 1):

Your onClick handlers are being called continuously. Change them to functions that return the function you wish to call and this should fix your issue.

So,

- Instead of: `<List.Item onClick={{this.showModal(123)} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}>`
- We do: `<List.Item onClick={() => {this.showModal(123)} } style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}>`

updated [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7phgq2)